# jQuery sum table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sum table cell

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input class="price" type="text" value="100"></td>
        <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input class="price" type="text" value="100"></td>
        <td><input class="quantity" type="text" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="summary">
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td id="total_price"></td>
            <td id="total_quantity"></td>
            <td class="second"></td>
            <td class="third"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>    
</table>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        var quantity = 0;
        $('.price').each(function() {
            sum += (parseInt($('.price').val()) * parseInt($('.price').val()));
            quantity += parseInt($('.quantity').val();
        });

        $('#total_price').html(sum);
        $('#total_quantity').html(quantity);
    })
</script>
```

Output must be: Total sum: 700; Total quantity: 7

Comment: Is it some school assignment ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is how to sum `price*quantity` all cell

Comment: Hint: think about what $(".quantity") and $(".price") will return. Then look at the documentation for each: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: missing to close `)` here `quantity += parseInt($('.quantity').val();`

Comment: @Jai Not at all duplicate

Comment: so vote for close, why people playing to downvote this question?

Comment: @Jai haters gonna be hate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `$('.price')` to `$(this)`, to refer the element inside the callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var quantity = 0;
    $('.price').each(function() {
        var price = $(this);
        var q = price.closest('tr').find('.quantity').val();
        sum += parseInt(price.val()) * parseInt(q);
        quantity += parseInt(q);
    });

    $('#total_price').html(sum);
    $('#total_quantity').html(quantity);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/swT5F/8/)

Comment: in sum must be `price*quantity`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` in `$.each()` like,

```
$('.price').each(function() {
   sum += (parseInt($(this).val())*parseInt($(this).val()));
   quantity += parseInt($this.closest('tr').find('.quantity').val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax errors.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        var quantity = 0;
        $('.price').each(function() {
            sum += (parseInt($('.price').val(), 10)*parseInt($('.price').val(), 10));
            quantity += parseInt($('.quantity').val(), 10);
        });

        $('#total_price').html(sum);
        $('#total_quantity').html(quantity);
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, using index of each method,

```
var sum = 0;
var quantity = 0;
$('.price').each(function(i){
    sum += $('.price')[i].value * $('.quantity')[i].value;
    quantity += $('.quantity')[i].value * 1;
});
$('#total_price').html(sum);
$('#total_quantity').html(quantity);
```

here this on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75UUz/)

Answer (score 1):

Correct you jquery to this:

```
var sum = 0;
var quantity = 0;
$('.price').each(function (i) {
    sum += $('.price')[i].value * $('.quantity')[i].value;
    quantity += $('.quantity')[i].value * 1;
});
$('#total_price').html(sum);
$('#total_quantity').html(quantity);
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ekzWJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

i was using parent class concept to get the quantity value. now it work find try it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var quantity = 0;
    var singleProduct,singleQuantity;

    $('.price').each(function() {
      singleProduct = parseInt($(this).val());
      console.log(singleProduct);
      singleQuantity = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find('.quantity').val());


      sum = sum+(singleProduct*singleQuantity);
      quantity = quantity+singleQuantity;
    });
    console.log(sum+"-"+quantity);
    $('#total_price').html(sum);
    $('#total_quantity').html(quantity);
```

});