# calculate amount on change of rate for each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my table which is dynamically generated. Means rows are generated through query result loop. But I am displaying here as simple html to avoid confusion.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Particulars</th>
<th>Packing</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>
 <input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:80%;' readonly='' value='".$row->quantity."'/> 
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
<td><input type='text' style='width:100%;' class='amount' readonly=''/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>
<input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:80%;' readonly='' value='".$row->quantity."'/>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
<td><input type='text' style='width:100%;' class='amount' readonly=''/></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>
<input type='text' class='quantity' style='width:80%;' readonly='' value='".$row->quantity."'/>
</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rate"></td>
<td><input type='text' style='width:100%;' class='amount' readonly=''/> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In every row rate and quantity will be different. So I want the value in quantity and rate and multiply them and display amount in respective td's input box. Question is user is going to enter rate for each row and then only will be amount display in amount input box. So how do I do this? Using jquery or use rate div's blur event or any other way of doing it??

Comment: jquery blur is your best bet here. You will need to uniquely identify each div in one `tr` and multiply the value based on the data entered by user.

Comment: I already did  that but when I change rate for first row, then it will assign calculated amount to each row's amount input box

Comment: Yeah that is the reason you need to uniquely identify each `tr`. You have not specified an id for any of your `td`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the blur of the rate input field.Each time you blur,get the quantity value using the appropriate selectors .This could be done much easier using other functions try researching it .You need to validate against each input to check it is a valid one.hope that helps u mate.. :)

```
$('input[name=rate]').on('blur',function(){
       var rate=$(this).val();
       var quantity = $(this).parent().parent().find('.quantity').val();
       var amount = rate*quantity;
       $(this).parent().parent().find('.amount').val(amount);
    });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eyvvxadh/)

**FYI**

Rather than copy paste the code.Try reading more of the functions that are being used mate..

[blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

[selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: what is the version of jquery u are using..?

Comment: Now table is populating but alert is not in blur event. Please suggest me changes for jquery version 1.5.2

Comment: You need to replace the `on('blur'` to `live('blur'`

Comment: I should be sayin,u are using a very old version of jQuery right now.Try updating it

Comment: one more question..If I want to display total amount of amount column then how do I do that??

Comment: use `each` function mate.. check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456326/jquery-sum-table-cells

Comment: Ok I m trying to implement it.

Comment: @Outlooker Now If I want to store that table data into codeigniter session..is it possible? And If yes then how?

Comment: @Hoja.M.A Now If I want to store that table data into codeigniter session..is it possible? And If yes then how?

Comment: @KedarB I think you should be opening a new question mate. :)

Comment: @Outlooker can I access rate by it's class name means like this input[class=rate]

Comment: `$(.classname').on('blur',function(){` would be enough

Answer (score 1):

### You could use like this it manages preventing of string typing in text box

```
$('body').on('blur', '.rate',function(e){
    var row = $(this);
    e = (e) ? e : window.event;
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && charCode!=8 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    findSum(row)    
    return true;
});


function findSum(obj){
   var sum = 0;
   var rate = parseInt(obj.val());
   var qty = parseInt(obj.closest('tr').find('.quantity').val());
   sum = rate*qty; 
    if(!isNaN(sum)){
        obj.closest('tr').find('.amount').val(sum);
    }
    else{
         obj.closest('tr').find('.amount').val('0');
    }    
}
```

### Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/qnaqa595/19/